# class pdo not found laravel

Tags: laravel, pdo, cpanel

So here is the issue, My `laravel 5.0` was working fine.. I basically have setup to domains, one like `dev.mydomain.com` and another 'mydomain.com'.I do all the testing in my `dev` site.. 
Just few moment ago, I created this `dev` domain. After then, the live site started giving me an error called `Class PDO not found. FatalErrorException in ConnectionFactory.php line 179` but my dev site is working totally fine.. 
On searching out, I found such errors occurs when `PDO extension` is not enabled but my dev site under the same subdomain is working fine. I have also enabled `PDO extension` in my `php.ini` that the application is using currently.. How should i resolve this issue. someone please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strange I am answering myself.. If someone face this problem, make sure you set the `php.ini` to be recursive. Just add

```
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/<<username>>/public_html
```

in `public_html/.htaccess`

It worked for me :)