# Class 'PDO' not found laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I'm building an application, and things worked well on localhost. After uploading the files to a host, though, I'm getting this error:

[image: error]

How can I fix it?

Comment: have you run on server `composer install`

Comment: Which hosting provider are you using? It looks like PDO isn't enabled in PHP, so you'd need to work with them to get that enabled.

Comment: Pretty sure `composer install` isn't going to help. What version of PHP are you running on your local host? What platform is your local host using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [class pdo not found laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34128764/class-pdo-not-found-laravel)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No solution here works for my “Class 'PDO' not found.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49797834/no-solution-here-works-for-my-class-pdo-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

Verify that php pdo extension is installed on your server (with phpinfo() for example), otherwise run

```
sudo apt install php7.1-pdo
```

(of course change with your php version)